# How to check the amount of RAM

Tags: r, ram

I want to make a function that imports data in different numbers of batches depending on how much RAM is available on someone's system. But how can I find the amount of available RAM in R? I can use `memory.size()` but that only works for Windows.

Comment: You are not going to implement one method to do this.  Your going to have to detect the platform then use different methods.

Comment: *"If you have to ask for the price, you cannot afford it."*  This looks the wrong approach as memory and resource management is handled by the operating system.  As Ramhound said, your approach will become platform-dependent.

Comment: The idea is to get a crude value that works somewhat as a default. For example, 1 batch with 12gb, 2 with 6gb, etcetera. Platform can be found with `Sys.info()` so platform dependent approach should be possible right?

Comment: Warning message:
'memory.size()' is Windows-specific

Comment: Warning message: `memory.size()` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Given the warnings concerning platform-dependency discussed in the earlier comment, you could for example parse `/proc/meminfo` on Linux:

```
$ grep MemFree /proc/meminfo 
MemFree:          573660 kB
$ awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo 
565464
```

You could try the second approach via `system(..., intern=TRUE)`, or even via a pipe connection.

*Edit some 5+ years later:* In R, and just following what the previous paragraph hinted at:

```
R> memfree <- as.numeric(system("awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", 
+                               intern=TRUE))
R> memfree
[1] 3342480
R>
```

Comment: I recommend to use `gc()` before calling this function to get the true amount of available memory.

Comment: Is the output unit bytes? R in windows usually specifies

Comment: for those that prefer copy-pasteable code: `as.numeric(system("awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", intern=TRUE))`

Comment: This is not allowed by CRAN.

Comment: @xiaodai do you know why? I have heard cran doesn't like `system()` calls, but I don't believe there's any complete ban. I think cran libraries need to work across all of windows/osx/unix/linux, perhaps this command stumbles on some platform (I don't know that for sure, just trying to guess why it would be denied).

Comment: I don't know why but my package got taken down cos I used it. So don't use it in a package.

Comment: @F.Privé How does `gc()` be useful in this context? Should the info be gathered from `Ncells` or `Vcells` output?

Comment: @Prradep It is useful because it gets rid of all the things that can be cleaned up to free some memory.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. How to infer about the RAM availability from this output?

Comment: Given that in the question it is asked about the available RAM, wouldn't `MemAvailable` make more sense than `MemFree`? (cache would not be free, but it is available)

Answer (score 14):

I would recommend using `memuse::Sys.meminfo()`.

Comment: I prefer this to `benchmarkme::get_ram` because the `memuse` package doesn't need any dependencies.

Answer (score 10):

Now you can do that with `benchmarkme::get_ram` function.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/benchmarkme/benchmarkme.pdf

Comment: `get_ram()` can not get the available memory.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the solutions already presented, I wrote a base R workaround that avoids package dependencies (didn't want to add to the current dependencies in the package):

```
available_memory <- function()
{

  # Get operating system
  OS <- tolower(Sys.info()["sysname"])

  # Branch based on OS
  if(OS == "windows"){ # Windows

    # System information
    system_info <- system("systeminfo", intern = TRUE)

    # Get available memory
    value <- system_info[
      grep("Available Physical Memory", system_info)
    ]

    # Remove extraneous information
    value <- gsub("Available Physical Memory: ", "", value)
    value <- gsub("\\,", "", value)
    
    # Convert to bytes
    value_split <- unlist(strsplit(value, split = " "))
    
    # Check for second value
    bytes <- as.numeric(value_split[1]) * switch(
      value_split[2],
      "KB" = 1e03,
      "MB" = 1e06,
      "GB" = 1e09
    )

  }else if(OS == "linux"){ # Linux
    
    # Split system information
    info_split <- strsplit(system("free", intern = TRUE), split = " ")
    
    # Remove "Mem:" and "Swap:"
    info_split <- lapply(info_split, function(x){gsub("Mem:", "", x)})
    info_split <- lapply(info_split, function(x){gsub("Swap:", "", x)})
    
    # Get actual values
    info_split <- lapply(info_split, function(x){x[x != ""]})
    
    # Bind values
    info_split <- do.call(rbind, info_split[1:2])
    
    # Get free values
    bytes <- as.numeric(info_split[2, info_split[1,] == "free"])
    
  }else{ # Mac
    
    # System information
    system_info <- system("top -l 1 -s 0 | grep PhysMem", intern = TRUE)

    # Get everything after comma
    unused <- gsub(" .*,", "", system_info)
    
    # Get values only
    value <- gsub("PhysMem: ", "", unused)
    value <- gsub(" unused.", "", value)
    
    # Check for bytes
    if(grepl("M", value)){
      bytes <- as.numeric(gsub("M", "", value)) * 1e06
    }else if(grepl("G", value)){
      bytes <- as.numeric(gsub("G", "", value)) * 1e09
    }else if(grepl("K", value)){
      bytes <- as.numeric(gsub("K", "", value)) * 1e03
    }
    
  }
  
  # Return bytes
  return(bytes)

}
```

It returns available memory in bytes and generally works (in my testing)