# Stop before RAM-swap to disk

Tags: r

I'm troubleshooting why my R-script uses too much RAM, and need to find where it occurs so I can start looking for a solution. The problem is that whenever the RAM is exceeded, the computer starts to swap to disk followed by 20 minutes of frustrating computer-freezings, R-restart, and need for reloading everything.

Can I make the script stop before the RAM is full? I suppose a code like this is what I need. But I can't figure out the "not sure 1" and "not sure 2" functions needed to get the actual situation.

```
installed.RAM <- notsure1()
used.RAM <- notsure2()
stopifnot(used.RAM < 0.9*installed.RAM)
```

What could notsure1() and notsure2() be?

I use R on Ubuntu (with RStudio Server). 16GB of RAM.

Comment: Partially what you need at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457290/how-to-check-the-amount-of-ram-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux / MAC OSX:

```
installed.RAM <- as.numeric(system("awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo",intern=TRUE));
used.RAM <- installed.RAM - as.numeric(system("awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", intern=TRUE));
```