# Complete R Session Size

Tags: r, session

Due to I constantly reach memory size limit in my R Session (8GB Windows PC) I start to `remove` big objects loaded in. However once I reach this limit, removing objects seems not to work.

So, I was wondering if there's a way to get the R Session size. I know that it's possible to retrieve objects' size (saw in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395270/determining-memory-usage-of-objects)).I want to know if there's a way to count the complete R Session size though (loaded packages, objects, etc).

Thank you!

Comment: You may be disappointed with the results. The limitations on constructing a new object are two-fold. One; in most instances a temporary object is construced and then copied. Two, the limit on object size is set by the maximum _contiguous_ space, rather than the total unused space.

Comment: Actually @F.Privé's answer was just perfect for me. Thank you though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally use this function to get the available memory:

```
getAvailMem <- function(format = TRUE) {

  gc()

  if (Sys.info()[["sysname"]] == "Windows") {
    memfree <- 1024^2 * (utils::memory.limit() - utils::memory.size())
  } else {
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/6457769/6103040
    memfree <- 1024 * as.numeric(
      system("awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", intern = TRUE))
  }

  `if`(format, format(structure(memfree, class = "object_size"),
                      units = "auto"), memfree)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the total memory used by R, you may try `mem_used()` from `pryr` package. Unlike `memory.size`, this one is not OS dependent, because it uses the R function `gc()` underneath it. Try to look in the function body and also this `pryr:::node_size` and `pryr:::show_bytes`

```
pryr::mem_used()
```

The help file `?pryr::mem_used` describes

> R breaks down memory usage into Vcells (memory used by vectors) and
>   Ncells (memory used by everything else). However, neither this
>   distinction nor the "gc trigger" and "max used" columns are typically
>   important. What we're usually most interested in is the the first
>   column: the total memory used. This function wraps around gc() to
>   return the total amount of memory (in megabytes) currently used by R.

You can also use `pryr::mem_change` to track the size of the memory used by the R code. Try the example in its documentation page.

The numbers such as `28L` and `56L` used to refer node size with `pryr:::node_size` comes from the help file of `?gc`, which describes

> gc returns a matrix with rows "Ncells" (cons cells), usually 28 bytes
>   each on 32-bit systems and 56 bytes on 64-bit systems, and "Vcells"
>   (vector cells, 8 bytes each),

After removing a large object run `gc()` to free memory